# com.android.deskclock.ALARM_ALERT Not Working

Tags: android, android-alarms

I had an application that used to work before the latest google update for the clock application, did they change the com.android.deskclock.ALARM_ALERT to another Action. adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.deskclock.ALARM_ALERT still works though.
are there any alternatives to using adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.deskclock.ALARM_ALERT in a broadcastReceiver

Answer (score 2):

I have been looking into implementing a way to detect when android stock alarm is ringing. I found many examples of the solution you used, but it does not work for me either. I ended up implementing NotificationListenerService and detecting when the alarm notification is created. By looking at the notification it is possible to determine if the alarm is pending, ringing or snoozed.

I hope this provides an alternative for you. If you do figure out how to make your solution work, I would like to see it :)